# How to prevent re-use of authorization after logout

Tags: c#, .net, json, security, forms-authentication

I have a project in C# which has some administrative functions behind a login screen.

During a recent pentest, we were dinged with a potential for attack: if the user submits a form, logs out, and the form post is repeated (using burp or a similar tool) the server still sees them as logged in and responds correctly.

The entire 'Admin' controller is set to `[Authorize]` with appropriate roles set.  On logout, I am calling

```
FormsService.SignOut();
Session.Clear();
Session.Abandon();
```

and redirecting the user to a start page.

Everything I have read indicates that this should be all I need to do to prevent this from happening.  That said, I can do the following:

1. Log on to my administration area
2. Perform a search (a JSON POST action, captured in burp)
3. See search results
4. Logout
5. Repeat the JSON POST in burp (which contains an '.ASPXAUTH' cookie)
6. See a server response in burp which matches the earlier response

What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: In general to prevent replay attacks you could use challenge-response authentication with nonce.

Comment: `Session.Abandon` should clear the server-side session; that should not work.

Comment: @SLaks: So I have read.  Yet, it still occurs.  I've performed the testing myself.

Comment: can you change the  session id?

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan: I can certainly try, can you recommend a method I could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot more experimentation, I have found a solution!

When the user logs in, I do the following:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application.Lock();
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application[HttpContext.User.Identity.Name] = true;
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application.UnLock();
```

and I reverse it when the user logs out (before killing Session can signing them out of FormsService).

Then, I take advantage of the fact that we already have a [custom AuthorizeAttribute override](http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2011/07/24/writing-your-own-custom-aspnet-mvc-authorize-attributes) to do this in the 'OnAuthorization' method:

```
/* Some other customer stuff that isn't relevant */

base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application[filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name] != null &&
    ((bool)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application[filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name]) == true)
{
    //The user is ok to log in, and should be validated now.
}
else
{
    HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
}
```

By storing the user's logged-in status in the application state, I am able to confirm their logged in status.

Some people seem to believe that a static class would be better than accessing the application state in MVC, but the Application is better for me in this case (largely because it is more familiar to the other people who will be maintaining the code and for ease of Unit Tests).